# Set database engine to sqlcipher in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am trying to use `sqlcipher` with my `Django` application. My current database is `sqlite`. I am following this official github instruction to integrate `sqlcipher` successfully :

```
https://github.com/codasus/django-sqlcipher
```

In, `settings.py` I have already added `sqlcipher` in `INSTALLED_APPS` . I am having problem to set database engine to `sqlcipher.backend` . Previously it was,

`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',`

I changed it to,

```
'ENGINE': 'sqlcipher.backend'
```

Error is showing,

```
Error was: No module named backend.base
```

Probably, I am missing something.

Comment: Go into site-packages -> Django -> backend is there a folder called "sqlcipher"? My first guess is change your code to  `'ENGINE': django.db.backends.sqlcipher.backend`.

Comment: Hi, sqlcipher is present here, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages , in this location I can see a folder sqlcipher. I installed it through pip.

Comment: Also, I can not see a backend folder within sqlcipher. In the git project repo, there is a folder called backend. But, it is not present here. I installed it using pip. Not sure, what is wrong.